# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS: 'Network Unreachable' when doing ping

Tags: server

I have changed my .yaml file in my Ubuntu Server because I need to access it using SSH protocol from another Ubuntu machine (both are virtualized in VirtualBox). After, I have applied changes and tried to do a ping 8.8.8.8, but it gives me the "Network Unreachable" message. What am I doing wrong? before changing the .yaml file the ping is correct.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.200/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

I have also set the Ubuntu Server net to bridget in its configuration options. Both versions are 20.04